# Second order differential equation stuck

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$y^{\prime\prime}+P(x)y'+Z(x)y=0$
is second order homogeneous differential equation. 
if yp is particular solution then $y=y_p\cdot u$, we can transform $u$ into first order differential equation. 

If $m(m-1)+mxP+x^2Q=0$, $y_p=x^m$
if $m^2+mP+Q=0$, $yp=e^mx$

question:
1.$x^2y^{\prime\prime}+3xy'+y=0$, find $y$ 
here I don't understand, the answer in the book said that $m=-1$ so $y=1/x$
I'm stuck here why $m=-1$? and why it choose $m(m-1)+mxP+x^2Q=0$??
Can someone explain this to me?
if $P=3x$ here and $Q=1$ but what is the point to find $m$?

Answer (score 0):

This is a Cauchy-Euler-Differential equation. you can solve it by using $y(x)=x^m$ as a trial function. You will obtain:

$$m(m-1)x^{m-2}x^2+3xmx^{m-1}+x^{m}=0 \implies \left[m(m-1)+3m+1\right]x^m=0.$$

Assuming $x\neq 0$ we can obtain $m^2+2m+1=0\implies m=-1$ (double root). Now, use $y(x)=x^{-1}u(x)$ to reduce the order of the differential equation.

Comment: hello thanks for answering my question! is this problem only can be solved by Cauchy-Euler differential equation? here using Cauchy-Euler equation is just to find the particular solution? sorry to ask again what if the question is not in the form of  $ax^2y"+bxy'-y=0$? like (x-1)y"-xy'+y=0? how to to find the a,b, and c?

Comment: This case is the easiest, because you will get two linearly independent solutions which can be combined by premultiplying with constants and adding to form the general solution